# Undef values from CSV file giving undesirable result

Tags: perl

I am having a CSV file Sample.csv like below named

```
    Name,Memory,Encoding,Extra 1,Extra 2
    ,d,,h,b
    FUSE_1,36,30,37,15
    FUSE_1,36,28,36,31
    Name1,1TB,00000001,30,010
    Name1,1TB,00000010,52,001
```

I am parsing this file and want to retrieve some values from the file. What I want is Only those names from the first row for which corresponding value is present in 2nd row. Means I want to get Memory,Extra 1 and Extra 2 as corresponding value is present in 2nd row (d,h and b). For which What I am doing is I am storing the values of both the rows in separate arrays and then I am traversing the array for 2nd row and the indexes corresponding to which value is present in this that corresponding index value I am taking from 1st array and storing it in second array.The code which I am using is-

```
my $iniFilename = "Sample.csv";
open(my $fi,'<',$iniFilename) or die "Can't open $iniFilename";
while(my $row=<$fi>){
if($row_no == 0)
{
    chomp($row);
    $row=~ s/\A\s+//g;
    $row=~s/\R//g;
    if(length($row))
    {
        @fuse_name_initial = split(/,/,$row);
    }
}
    elsif($row_no == 1)
    {
        chomp($row);
        $row=~ s/\A\s+//g;
        $row=~s/\R//g;
        if(length($row)){
        @fuse_data_type_initial =split(/,/,$row);
        }
    }
    $row_no++;
}
my $trace=0;
foreach (@fuse_data_type_initial)
{
    if($_)
    {
        if($fuse_name_initial[$trace] !~ /Extra Fuse/){
            push @column_no_for_fuse_value,($trace+1);
            push @fuse_names , $fuse_name_initial[$trace];
            push @fuse_data_type ,$_ ;
            $trace++;
        }
        else{
            push @extra_fuse_data_type ,$_ ;
            $trace++;
        }
    }
 }
```

Now I am expecting the @fuse_names array to reflect names "Memory" as "Extra Fuse1" and "Extra Fuse2" is filtered out using regex but instead I am getting very bad result. I am getting three elements in the @fuse_names- Name,Memory,Encoding . Can Somebody please tell me What I am doing wrong in the code??

> > EDIT : When I am changing 2nd row to ",d,,," and following @Dada method then it should only take "Memory" from 1st row but instead it is taking everything after memory i.e Memory,Encoding,Extra Fuse1,Extra Fuse2

And then I printed the length of @filter array.It should ideally be 5 with 1 defined value and 4 other undef value but strangely the length of @filter came out to be 2. It is really Confusing.

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have been asking a lot of questions lately, and it's hard to help you when we can't run your code. Here for instance, we have to guess how is `$fi` initialized, and whether you forgot to copy/past the increment of `$row_no` or not... If you want us to spend time helping you, then spend time writing good questions.

Comment: I am creating these codes depicting my requirement from the actual code by filtering all  the confidential details but trying maintaining the soul of the problem. While doing so I may miss some information(although I have cross checked the question before posting ;) ). Anyways thanks for mentioning the requirement. I have edited the code please look into it now-@Dada

Comment: Perhaps move the 2 statements `$trace++;` out of the `if($_)` clause and put 1 at the bottom of the `foreach (@fuse_data_type_initial)
` loop?

Comment: Your code looks for `Extra Fuse` but I assume that it corresponds to `Extra 1/2` in the csv you provided. The point of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is precisely that *you* should provide us with a *verifiable* example. Also, what are supposed to be `@column_no_for_fuse_value`, `@fuse_names`, `@fuse_data_type` and `@extra_fuse_data_type` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is pretty bad for several reasons. Instead of trying to fix them, which would leave you with a bad-but-working code, I'm going to point them out, and suggest a better way.

- You first `while(my $row = <$fi>)` iterates over the whole file when you are only interested in the first two rows. You should just use `<$fi>` twice to read the first two lines:

  ```
  my $headers = <$fi>;
  my $filters = <$fi>;
  ```
- You shouldn't duplicate code. In particular, you wrote twice

  ```
  chomp($row);
  $row=~ s/\A\s+//g;
  $row=~s/\R//g;
  ```

  Whereas you could have put that only once at the beginning of the while.
- Same thing for `$trace++`: you want it done at every iteration of your `foreach` loop; there is no reason to put it in at the end of the `if` and at the end of the `else`.
- **always** `use strict` and `use warnings`.

---

Here is what I suggest instead:

```
use strict;  # Always use strict and warnings!
use warnings;

my $iniFilename = "Sample.csv";
open(my $fi,'<',$iniFilename) or die "Can't open $iniFilename";

my @headers = split ',', <$fi> =~ s/\A\s+|\s+\Z//gr, -1;
my @filter  = split ',', <$fi> =~ s/\A\s+|\s+\Z//gr, -1;
for my $i (0 .. $#filter) {
    $headers[$i] = undef if !$filter[$i] || $filter[$i] eq "" ;
}
# @headers now contains (undef, "Memory", undef, "Extra 1", "Extra 2")
```

If you need the index of `@headers` that are not `undef`:

```
my @headers_indices = grep { defined $headers[$_] } 0 .. $#headers;
```

If you need just the names of the non-undef headers:

```
my @non_undef_headers = grep { defined $_ } @headers;
```

---

Finally, since you are parsing CSV files, you might want to use a CSV parser ([Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) for example), rather than `split /,/`. (the latter will misbehave with quoted fields containing commas or newlines (and probably has other issues that I'm not thinking about right now))

Comment: I cannot emphasize enough that Text::CSV(_XS) should be used instead. http://thomasburette.com/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/

Comment: Thanks for such an explanatory and concise answer.It is exactly fulfilling my requirement. Thank you for investing your time-@Dada

Comment: Can you please look into the edits that I have added to the question. Following your exact code when I am changing 2nd row I am not getting the expected result. Can you please look into it and tell me why it is happening and what is the workaraound-@Dada

Comment: @rikki Indeed, my bad, it's fixed. I overlooked the fact that `split` removes trailing empty fields by default. Two fixes possible: use `-1` (or any negative number) as last argument to `split` (which causes `split` to not remove trailing empty fields), or iterate over `@headers` rather than `@filter`: `for my $i (0 .. $#headers)` (but this could suffer from the same issues if the last headers are empty).

Comment: Hi its working fine now. I have marked your answer as accepted. Thanks a lot for helping-@ Dada